# Is the phrase "PM who have approved" correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs

> PM who have approved

Is the phrase correct?

I think it should be "PM who has approved" (PM: Project Manager). Am I wrong?

Comment: Neither of those is a complete sentence. Please give a just a bit more context so we can help. But I'll answer stochastically: you're right, if it's one PM (singular), then it should be *has*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both might be ok depending on what PM means.

> The Prime Minister who has approved
>
> The Project Managers who have approved

Comment: +1 correct - though it's worth noting that "Project Managers" would usually be abbreviated to "PMs". But the same argument also applies because it could refer to a group such as "Product Marketing" :-)

Comment: But PM could stand for "Project Management": referring to a group. In that case, the plural verb would be correct. Then again a singular verb might also be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is said above is correct. When you are taking *PM* as *Prime Minister* (singular), usage of has* is correct. But when it's regarding a group like project managers (plural), usage of *have* is right.

It's all about whether it has been referred to a single person or to a group. If plural, use *have* and if singular, use *has*;that's it.

E.g.:

> Mr. Jack has a Mercedes Benz car (singular).

Vs.

> The people who always blame others do not have time to improve themselves (plural).